# How to find the radius of a graph when eccentricities of all vertices are the same?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

[image: graph]

I've came to a conclusion that eccentricities of all vertices are the same in the picture above:

> *e(A)=2*
> *e(B)=2*
> *e(C)=2*
> *e(D)=2*
> *e(E)=2*
> *e(F)=2*

Since eccentricities of all vertices are the same, does that mean that the radius of a graph equals $2$ as well and that all vertices are the central points?

Comment: Yes. The radius and diameter are both equal to 2.

Comment: Somewhat entertaining terminology: The graph in question here (as with any graph in which the eccentricity of every vertex is the same) may be called *"self-centered"*.